# highlight parts of code different than the rest of the code

Tags: highlight, vscode-extensions, monaco-editor

I want to create a plugin for vs-code that adds custom highlight to js:

```
const t = () => {
  return "<div class="test"><a>Hello</a></div>"
}
```

I want the HTML section to be highlight just like html and the js section the be highlight just like js. Is there a way to set specific highlight for specific secitions of the code in monaco?

[Just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO8Ft.png) but with quotations

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Any string literal in JavaScript should be treated as an HTML string? Or how do you decide which strings are HTML and which not and should not be subjected to HTML syntax highlighting?

Comment: I don't want to make the extension public so I could use some ugly methods like searching for the keyword "div" or something